# Open a Make Meeting field inside colorbox

Tags: 7, entities, theming, javascript

I am using the [Make Meeting Scheduler](https://drupal.org/project/makemeeting) for my site, which is a Doodle-like scheduler module. This module makes it possible to insert a field (only field, not available as block) into a node. However, I need to open this field inside Colorbox.

I know a possible workaround would be to create separate nodes with only the Make Meeting field and then connect them to the original nodes where I need them, but this is definitely not an elegant solution.

I'm really not good with Drupal templates and that is why I haven't come up with a better solution. I suppose I should edit the template, print a link with the class "colorbox-load" and have that link point to the Make Meeting div. Problem is, I am currently clueless as to how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is through [views](https://drupal.org/project/views). You can configure a view with an "Contextual Filter" of the node id to show and then configure it to show your makemeeting field here. Here's a screenshot of a view that worked for me (note the important parts are marked with arrows.

[image]

Then when I go to */meeting-popup/6* (where 6 is the id of a node with a meeting field) i see the following.

[image]

Then you can add a link to /meeting-popup/ on the nodes page using the lightbox-load class so it will showup in a popup.

Lastly you can theme the meeting-popup pages so that they only show the content and don't show any regions/sidebars, etc.

Alternatively you can have views make it into a "block" if you know of a good way to do it that way.

Comment: Okay, I managed to make everything work except the contextual filter. It's my lack of knowledge, I'm sure you explained it quite well. Could you please clarify that? I added a link to my nodes that goes like this <a href="/make-meeting" class="colorbox-load">Make an appointment</a>, but I still get all of my fields in the colorbox. Could you please help me with the contextual filters bit? How do I get only the fields for the specfic node?

Comment: The link needs to be /make-meeting/10, if 10 is the node id of the current node the user is looking at. So you will need to do some PHP ($node->nid) or use tokens  [node:nid] depending on how you are inserting the link.