# Attaching multiple webforms to a node

Tags: 7, webforms

I need not one, but three different webforms for my content type. So far I've seen that the webform module allows for only one webform per node. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

To clarify why I can't use the easy solution using blocks - I need to have each instance of the webform prepopulated with the node title (the node the webform is attached to) and I also need it to open in a lightbox. For making that work with one webform I used [this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96396/open-a-make-meeting-field-inside-colorbox), however, adding more webforms to the mix makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Webform allow embed form as block, so you can build 3 webforms, then show one in main content, and other 2 as blocks...

Comment: Actually, this doesn't really solve my problem because I really need to have the webforms to be _attached_ to the node. Each webform needs to have prepopulated fields from the node title they were submitted from.